# Issue with installing PIL

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install PIL. I have tried going through the settings and do it that way. When that didn't work, I tried to do it through the terminal. I got an error message:

```
C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Paul's stuff\Paul\CpmpProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/Game.py"
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Paul's stuff/Paul/CpmpProject/Game.py", line 3
    pip install PIL
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

I have no idea how to install PIL now and am hoping someone can help me. I am working with python 3 and have updated pip and set up tools.

Comment: you mean installing PIL programatically?

Comment: try `pip install pillow`

Comment: You have to enter `pip install PIL` in the command-line/terminal not in the Python shell. Also, better install Pillow instead of PIL `pip install Pillow` because PIL is outdated.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to enter `pip install` on your command line, it's not valid Python code.

Also, as others have mentioned, install `pillow` instead of `PIL`, the interface is identical.